# Is there a way to filter elements in join table, in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have simple structure

- table of **artists**
- table of **events**
- joint table for many
  to many relationships between **artists** and **events** called **events_performers**

Each artist has multiple events, each event has multiple artists
Each event has `start_date_utc` field.

I want to get first 3 artists with events that start next year.

Basic query like

```
query {
  artists(limit:1, where:{artist_id:{_eq:"59e72613285acff772b6bd7e"}}) {
    artist_id    
    events_performers {
      event (where:{start_date_utc:{_gt:"2022-01-01"}}) {       
        title
        start_date_utc
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Tells me that  `"\"event\" has no argument named \"where\""` which is quite logical, event if event has object relationship with events table, where I have start_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct query:

```
query {
  artists(limit:1, where:{artist_id:{_eq:"59e72613285acff772b6bd7e"}}) {
    artist_id    
   events_performers(where: {event: {start_date_utc: {_gte: "2021-01-01"}}}) 
   {
      event {       
        title
        start_date_utc
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

The filter should be placed

- at **events_performers** step
- with 'event' field specifically mentioned